# How to display more data when a user clicks on the Dropdown of the Select Element?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular-reactive-forms

In the `SELECT` element, when the user doesn't click on it (default view), I want to display Option1 as : `VALUE1 VALUE2`. And when the user clicks on the `SELECT` element and opens the dropdown of options, I want to display Option1 as: `VALUE1 VALUE2 VALUE3`.

I will get the Value *1,2,3* from the API. I know how to get data/value from the API but I don't know how to display one more key/value when the user clicks on the `Select` field.

Comment: when a user clicks on the select field, set a boolean variable to true; inside your select field use an *ngIf to show the value 3 only when this boolean variable is true;

Answer (score 1):

A way i normally do is to insert a `for loop` in option tags which  is binding to a variable containing data in angular component. Everytime you fetch data from api, you need to add values into that variable to display changes.

```
<form [formGroup]="countryForm">
 <select formControlName="countryControl">
   <option [value]="country" 
           *ngFor="let country of countries">
           {{country}}
    </option>
 </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be using an array of elements to display the dropdown elements.
use `(click)="addElement()"` on the `select` and create this function `addElement()` in your component, and in this function just add the element in the array that is display as the dropdown elements.